# Change a 2 column website to 1 column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have Wordpress site with a 2 column portfolio. Unfortunately there are no possibilities to change it to a 1 column portfolio in the backend - but at small resolutions the layout automatically changes to a 1 column site.

http://hosting2015.esy.es/mw/immobilien/ausland/

So what happens in the code at this moment that makes this column change possible?

Comment: You can change the layout in the backend if you have admin access. You can go into Appearance > Editor and edit the CSS file. What is happening is a `@media` query and the styles associated with the layout. Your site is also using `isotope` to render the grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), which are breakpoints in the interface the author declares. Basically, the author said "when the viewport is less than 480 pixels, let each tile take up 100% of its container in width, forcing the one column stack. When greater than 480, give each tile a max-width of 300 pixels (or something like that) and let them float (or tile, if you will) as they please."